# Saving a audio recording in a folder

Tags: javascript, php, audio, audio-recording

I am using this GitHub project to record some audio on a website, I want to save that file in a folder instead of displaying it on the website.
https://github.com/addpipe/simple-web-audio-recorder-demo

The current version is creating a download link and displaying the audio clip on the website, I've attempted to send the data to PHP using AJAX.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "uploadAudio.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: "audio", blob,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data){
        alert('success');
      }
    });
```

and the PHP code I tried to save it as a file

```
    <?php
    $dir = "uploads/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"], $dir. "name");
    ?>
```

Am I thinking along the right lines? have you got any suggestions for a better way of doing this?

Comment: Is that working ?

Comment: @EduardoJunior It's not recognising anything by the name of 'audio' am I sending it correctly?

Comment: `data: "audio", blob,`  That's not correct.  If you want to use `$_FILES`, look into [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: You have to send form data to make `$_FILES` work (either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data). If you want to put the audio directly into the body, read from `php://input`.